# How do you say Good Day to all for a group of people?

Tags: translation

Kann Man sagt "Guten Tag zu Alles" to mean the he is saying good day to all in a group.

Answer (score 3):

I find the usual way to be just

> Hallo

while looking at everybody in the group.

If you want to emphasize that you really greet everybody, you can say

> Hallo zusammen

Which I (North German)  find more common to say than

> Hallo alle miteinander

which feels slightly outdated to me, but still works.

Of course you can replace Hallo with Guten Tag.

Comment: My first German manager used to write "Hallo zusammen".  Which when she wrote in English she would always directly translate to "Hello together", which always made me chuckle! (Which is probably why I never corrected her!)

Answer (score 3):

The *Nominativ* case, as suggested by πάντα ῥεῖ and infinitezero, is one (natural) option.

However, there are others. It's possible to use *Dativ* (*whom* do you wish a good day?):

> Guten Tag Euch allen!
>
> (...) allen Anwesenden einen Guten Tag.

If you use the right preposition, you may even use *Akkusativ*, e.g.:

> Guten Tag an alle!

Answer (score 2):

> Kann Man sagt "Guten Tag zu Alles"

That's wrong in many ways:

*Kann man sagt* muss *Kann man **sagen*** heissen.

*zu Alles* cannot be used to refer for a group of people.

The usual way to say that in German is

> Guten Tag alle miteinander.

Answer (score 2):

You could also say "Guten Tag allerseits".

Comment: That's a good solution. It is not too casual, but also not too stiff.